# Microsoft Teams App - how to create events in Outlook calendar?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to schedule Outlook calendar events from an MS Teams app?

As I understand, [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) would be an option. However, users would need to authenticate twice to use that (once when logging in to Teams, and once to get the token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're correct, on both points. Graph is the best way to go on this, and you would need to authenticate, unfortunately. It's not Teams the user is authenticating to, per se, it's -your app- that's needing to get a token in order to operate on the user's behalf.

For a Bot, your best option is the [Signin Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#signin-card), but for a Tab it's possible to do a ["silent" authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-silent-aad).

Answer (score 0):

@nagy.zsolt.hun, unfortunately there is no other way. You have to implement authentication.  Well the Silent authentication can reduce your repetitive login's as @Hilton Giesenow mentioned.